# GPUImageStillCamera image preview jumps when taking a photo

Tags: ios8, avfoundation, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I am taking a square cropped photo with `GPUImageStillCamera` and allowing the user to zoom the camera. When the user clicks to take a picture the camera jumps forward for a split second (as if the camera zoomed in even further past the area the user zoomed to and then immediately returns to the correct crop once the image is returned to screen). This only happens when the user has zoomed the camera. If they have not zoomed the camera the flicker/jump does not happen. (The image return has the correct crop whether or not the user has zoomed).

Thoughts?

Creating camera and adding square crop

```
//Add in filters
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

//Creating a square crop filter
cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.f, (720.0f/1280.0f)/2.0f, 1.f, (720.0f/1280.0f))];
```

Image zoom method

```
-(void)imagePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{ //Controlling the zoom scale as the user pinches the live preview

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    zoomOutAdder = 0.0f;
    if (currentScale > 2) {
        zoomOutAdder = currentScale;
    }
}


float addition = (recognizer.scale - lastScale);

if (addition > 0) {
    addition = addition *1.7;
}

if (addition < 0) {
    addition = addition *(1.7+zoomOutAdder);
}


currentScale = currentScale +addition;
lastScale = recognizer.scale;


 if (currentScale < 1) {
 currentScale = 1;
 }

 if (currentScale > 4) {
 currentScale =4;
 }

if (currentScale == 1) {
    zoomOutAdder = 0.0f;
}

cameraImagePreview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(currentScale, currentScale);

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    lastScale = 1.0f;
}
```

Take a photo method

```
      //Adjust crop based on zoom scale of the user
CGFloat zoomReciprocal = 1.0f / currentScale;
CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(((1.0f - zoomReciprocal) / 2.0f), (((1.0f- zoomReciprocal)*(720.0f/1280.0f)) / 2.0f) + ((720.0f/1280.0f)/2)) ;
CGRect newCrop =  cropFilter.cropRegion;
newCrop.origin.x = offset.x;
newCrop.origin.y = offset.y;
newCrop.size.width = cropFilter.cropRegion.size.width * zoomReciprocal;
newCrop.size.height = cropFilter.cropRegion.size.height *zoomReciprocal;
cropFilter.cropRegion = newCrop;
 */

//Place photo inside an image preview view for the user to decide if they want to keep it.
[stillCamera capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter:cropFilter withOrientation:imageOrientation withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *processedImage, NSError *error) {


    //Pause the current camera
    [stillCamera pauseCameraCapture];

    //Rest of method
```

***ADDED METHODS***

```
- (void) flipCamera {

if (stillCamera.cameraPosition != AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.65 animations:^{
        flipCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
    }];

} else {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.65 animations:^{
        flipCamera.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    }];
}
[self performSelector:@selector(rotateCamera) withObject:0 afterDelay:.2];
}


- (void) rotateCamera {

[stillCamera rotateCamera];

//Adjust flash settings as needed
[stillCamera.inputCamera lockForConfiguration:nil];
if (stillCamera.cameraPosition != AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
    [stillCamera.inputCamera setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
}

NSAttributedString *attributedFlash =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithString:@"off"
 attributes:
 @{
   NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:13.0f],
   NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.55],
   NSKernAttributeName : @(.25f)
   }];
flashLabel.attributedText = attributedFlash;

[UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
    [flash setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.55]];
}];

[stillCamera.inputCamera unlockForConfiguration];
}



- (void) changeFlash {

if (stillCamera.cameraPosition == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {//no flash available on front of camera
    return;
}

[stillCamera.inputCamera lockForConfiguration:nil];
if (stillCamera.inputCamera.flashMode == AVCaptureFlashModeOff) {
    [stillCamera.inputCamera setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
    [self animateFlashWithTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1] andString:@"on"];

} else if (stillCamera.inputCamera.flashMode == AVCaptureFlashModeOn) {
    [stillCamera.inputCamera setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
    [self animateFlashWithTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.55] andString:@"off"];
}

[stillCamera.inputCamera unlockForConfiguration];
}



- (void) animateFlashWithTintColor:(UIColor *)color andString:(NSString *)text {

//Set new text
NSAttributedString *attributedFlash =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithString:text
 attributes:
 @{
   NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:13.0f],
   NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.55],
   NSKernAttributeName : @(.25f)
   }];
flashLabel.attributedText = attributedFlash;

float duration = .7;

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:duration animations:^{
        [flash setTintColor:color];
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:.7/duration animations:^{
        flash.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

    }];

}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    flash.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}];
}


-(void) usePhoto {

if ([ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){
    NSLog(@"Do Not Have Right To Save to Photo Library");
}

//Save Image to Phone Album & save image
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(takenPhoto.image, nil, nil, nil);

//Save Image to Delegate
[self.delegate saveImageToDatabase:takenPhoto.image];
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissCamera) withObject:0 afterDelay:.4];
}
```

Some additional code showing the creation of the the various camera elements used to capture a photo.

```
centerPoint = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, (cameraHolder.frame.size.height+50+self.view.frame.size.height)/2);
cameraImagePreview = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cameraHolder.frame.size.width, cameraHolder.frame.size.width)];
[cameraHolder addSubview:cameraImagePreview];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTouch:)];
[cameraImagePreview addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imagePinch:)];
[cameraImagePreview addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];


float scaleForView = self.view.frame.size.width/720.0;
fullCameraFocusPoint = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 1280*scaleForView)];
fullCameraFocusPoint.center = CGPointMake(cameraHolder.frame.size.width/2, (cameraHolder.frame.size.width/2)+50);
[self.view insertSubview:fullCameraFocusPoint atIndex:0];

takenPhoto = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:cameraHolder.frame];
takenPhoto.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:takenPhoto];


//Add in filters
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

//Creating a square crop filter
cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.f, (720.0f/1280.0f)/2.0f, 1.f, (720.0f/1280.0f))];

//Create standard vignette filter
vignetteFilter = [[GPUImageVignetteFilter alloc] init]; //1
vignetteFilter.vignetteCenter = CGPointMake(.5, .5);
vignetteFilter.vignetteStart = 0.4f;
vignetteFilter.vignetteEnd = 1.08f;

//Add filters to photo
[cropFilter addTarget:vignetteFilter];
[stillCamera addTarget:cropFilter];
[vignetteFilter addTarget:cameraImagePreview];
[stillCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Comment: Quick comment... please edit your question and reformat your code...

Comment: @jesses.co.tt - Fix it... thanks for the note

Comment: So, you have two different gesture recognizers, one detecting a Tap, the other a Pinch+Zoom ? I'd guess it is some view interception, and not really anything to do with GPUImage... Can you post the Interface code, with logs ?

Comment: Yes, one detects a tap on a button below the image while the other detects a pinch on the actual live image previews and zooms the live image preview on the pinch. The tap triggers the `capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter` method which is when the jump occurs --- On the interface & logs is there a particular piece you would like. Still new to iOS and not exactly sure what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm just trying to see if one UI interaction is triggering/itercepting the one meant for the other gesture...

Comment: @jesses.co.tt I added the camera elements for creation... where are the logs you are asking for. Other then using NSLog (or a crash) I am not really sure where to see or get a log. Sorry I am not more knowledgable here and thanks for sticking with me :)

Comment: Hey. Yeah, I understand if what I was saying is unclear... I was suggesting/asking if you could add NSLog statements to the UI lifecycle and post that, so that we get an understanding of what happens when... your problem is definitely some type of order of operation error, so thats the only way we can really tell whats happening, unless you upload the code to GitHub and I can DL it from there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67181/discussion-between-chase-s-and-jesses-co-tt).